# How to do Unit test on a Button that jumps between activities? (android studio Junit5)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unit-testing, junit5

As the title, I am writing an android app using java,
I want to do a Unit test using **Junit5** on my button methods that look like this:

```
private void GoToAbout() {
        abtBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,About.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

That if users click on the button, they can jump from mainActivity to About activity.

although the function works perfectly when testing on my physical phone,
How do you usually write unit tests for methods like this?
(I mean it doesn't have an output for me to check)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to learn about MVP or any design patters.

In case of mine MVP should be like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainActivityContract.View {

private MainActivityContract.Presenter presenter = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    presenter = new MainPresenter(this);

    abtBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           presenter.onAboutButtonClick();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void goToAbout() {
    abtBtn.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,About.class));
}}
```

Presenter

```
public class MainPresenter implements MainActivityContract.Presenter{

private MainActivityContract.View view;

public MainPresenter(MainActivityContract.View view){
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public void onAboutButtonClick() {
    view.goToAbout();
}}
```

Contract

```
public interface MainActivityContract{
interface View{
    void goToAbout();
}

interface Presenter{
    void onAboutButtonClick();
}}
```

And the last unit test class

```
public class MainTest {

static MainActivityContract.View view = mock(MainActivityContract.View.class);

static MainActivityContract.Presenter presenter;

@BeforeAll
public static void setup(){
    presenter = new MainPresenter(view);
}


@Test
public void testAboutButtonIsClick(){
    presenter.onAboutButtonClick();
    verify(view, times(1)).goToAbout();;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am almost new to design patterns so I'll have a lot to learn, just want to ask, is the testing in your reply using mockito? is it checking how many times that the method was called?

Comment: Yes, mockito check method "goToAbout" has been call just one time after call "onAboutButtonClick" or you can use "verify(view).goToAbout()" in a simple way.